# Why is my player moving faster and faster when I use the controls. HTML web game

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an HTML5 web game and am in the process of making the player movement. I am not using any game engine, just pure HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. My problem is that whenever I load my game, it starts out fine where I can move around at normal speeds but if I move back and forth a few times, the player starts speeding up and if I keep doing this, it speeds up to unbearable speeds. I have no idea what is happening.
How my code works is when the key d is pressed then in the keysPressed object D is set to true instead of false,

```
let keysPressed = {
'd': false,
'a': false,
'w': false,
's': false,   }
```

Then, it executes a function that moves the player.

```
function move() {
if (keysPressed['d'] == true) { // check if its right
    let player = document.querySelector('.player');
    var id = setInterval(frame, 20);
    function frame() {
        if (keysPressed['d'] == false) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            player.style.left = player.offsetLeft + 2 + 'px';
        }
    }
}
if (keysPressed['a'] == true) { // check if its left
    let player = document.querySelector('.player');
    var id = setInterval(frame, 20);

    function frame() {
        if (keysPressed['a'] == false) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            console.log(player.offsetLeft)
            player.style.left = player.offsetLeft - 2 + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

}

I know that it isn't the cleanest code but I just wanna fix this bug first before tackling this.

Thanks

Comment: I would guess it's because you have the `setinterval` and the function it calls inside of the `move` function. I would think this would cause the player position to be updated multiple times per iteration

Comment: Will it call `setInterval` many times while the key is held down? Maybe use [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling setInterval many times over which is compounding and causing the symptom you're describing. I think you only need to call setInterval once, and then just change the left/right variables depending on the keypress.. something like

```
let intervalID, player = document.querySelector('.player'),
  dir, offset, isMoving = false;

function changeDirection(keysPressed) {
  if (!isMoving) move();
  if (keysPressed['d']) {
    dir = 'left';
    offset = 'offsetLeft';
  } else if (keysPressed['a']) {
    dir = 'right';
    offset = 'offsetRight';
  }
}

function move() { // called just once
  if (isMoving) return;
  isMoving = true;
  intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    player.style[dir] = (+player[offset] + 2) + 'px';
  }, 20);
}
```

Comment: So you said to call move() only once but where would I call it?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: btw offsetRight doesn't exist